# Especificar nome da tabela usando namespace no createQuery no Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Preciso criar uma consulta ao banco em uma tabela cujo nome é **order** e isso não pode ser alterado.
Fiz a seguinte query:

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT sum(o.orderPrice) 
                                            FROM  \App\Entity\Order  o 
                                            WHERE o.orderEventId = ?1
                                                  o.orderDate <= ?2
                                                  o.orderDate >= ?3")
                            ->setParameters(array(
                                                    1 => $event,
                                                    2 => ' LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) ',
                                                    3 => ' DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))-1 DAY)'
                                                 )
                                            );


    $dados['qtd_resultado'] = $query->getResult();
```

O namespace \App\Entity\Order indicado no FROM aponta para a seguinte Entity no doctrine:

```
namespace App\Entity;
```

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="order")
 */
class Order
{
}
```

O problema ocorre no FROM pois a palavra ORDER é reservada, assim no momento de montar a query o sistema apresenta erro de sintaxe.
Qual a maneira correta de informar o nome da tabela?

Comment: faz assim  select * from 'order'

Comment: entre aspas simples ele nao encara como comando e sim como texto